# Error: no matching function for call to 'endl(const char [6], int)'

Tags: c++

```
# include<iostream>  
# include<conio.h>   
# include<stdio.h>   
# include<stdlib.h>  
# include<windows.h> 
# include<cstdlib>   
# include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char   Loai_math_problem;
    int    Cau_tra_loi;
    int    x, So_hang_thu_nhat, So_hang_con_lai, Tong;
    int    So_tru, So_bi_tru, Hieu;
    int    Thua_so_thu_nhat, Thua_so_thu_hai, Thua_so_con_lai, Tich;
    int    So_chia, So_bi_chia, Thuong;
    system("cls");
    printf("Short program made by C++ can solve X from a math problem with a sign (+, -, x, /).\nVer1.2.");
    Sleep(1200);
    printf("\nPress any key to continue!");
    cau_tra_loi_chung://label chung
    getch();
    system("cls");
    printf("Okey! Let' start!\nType '+', '-', 'x', '/' to confirm.");
    Loai_math_problem=getch();
    switch(Loai_math_problem)
    {
        case '+'://label +
        {
        buoc_tra_loi_phan_1:
             printf("\nOkey!\nWhat type of 'x'?\nType '1' in case like 1+4=x or '2' in case x+1=5 also 1+x=5\n");
             scanf("%i", Cau_tra_loi);
             if(Cau_tra_loi==1)
             {
                printf("\nType the '1': ");
                scanf("%i", So_hang_thu_nhat);
                printf("\nType the '4': ");
                scanf("%i", So_hang_con_lai);
                printf(endl("X: %i", So_hang_thu_nhat + So_hang_con_lai)endl);//cout << endl <<  "X: " << So_hang_thu_nhat + So_hang_con_lai << endl;
             }
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 2)
             {
                printf("Type the '1': \n");
                scanf("%i", So_hang_con_lai);
                printf("Type the '5': \n");
                scanf("%i", Tong);
                printf("X: %i", Tong - So_hang_con_lai endl);//cout << "X: " << Tong - So_hang_con_lai << endl;
             }
             if(Cau_tra_loi<=0 ||Cau_tra_loi>=3)
             {
                printf("\nError: Invailid answer");
             }
             break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
        buoc_tra_loi_phan_2://label -
             printf("\nOkey!\nWhat type of 'x'?\nType '1' in case like 4-1=x or '2' in case x-1=3 or '3' 4-x=3\n");
             Cau_tra_loi=getch();
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 1)
             {
                printf("\nType the '4': ");
                scanf("%i", So_bi_tru);
                printf("\nType the '1': ");
                scanf("%i", So_tru);
                printf(endl"X: %i", So_bi_tru - So_tru endl);//cout << endl <<  "X: " << So_bi_tru - So_tru << endl;
             }
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 2)
             {
                printf("Type the '1': \n");
                scanf("%i", So_tru);
                printf("Type the '3': \n");
                scanf("%i", Hieu);
                printf("X: %i", So_tru + Hieu endl);//cout << "X: " << So_tru + Hieu << endl;
             }
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 3)
             {
                printf("Type the '4': \n");
                scanf("%i", So_bi_tru);
                printf("Type the '3': \n");
                scanf("%i", Hieu);
                printf("X: %i", So_bi_tru - Hieu endl);//cout << "X: " << So_bi_tru - Hieu << endl;
             }
             if(Cau_tra_loi<=0 || Cau_tra_loi>=4)
             {
                printf("\nError: Invailid answer");
             }
             break;
        }
        case 'x':
        {
        buoc_tra_loi_phan_3://label x
             printf("\nOkey!\nWhat type of 'x'?\nType '1' in case like 1 x 5 = X or '2' in case X x 1 = 5 also 1 x X = 5\n");
             Cau_tra_loi=getch();
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 1)
             {
                printf("\nType the '1': ");
                scanf("%i", Thua_so_thu_nhat);
                printf("\nType the '5': ");
                scanf("%i", Thua_so_thu_hai);
                printf(endl"X: %ld", Thua_so_thu_nhat * Thua_so_thu_hai endl);//cout << endl <<  "X: " << Thua_so_thu_nhat * Thua_so_thu_hai << endl;
             }
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 2)
             {
                printf("Type the '1': \n");
                scanf("%i", Thua_so_con_lai);
                printf("Type the '5': \n");
                scanf("%i", Tich);
                printf("X: %lf", Tich/Thua_so_con_lai endl);//cout << "X: " << Tich/Thua_so_con_lai << endl;
             }
             if(Cau_tra_loi<=0 || Cau_tra_loi>=3)
             {
                printf("\nError: Invailid answer");
             }
             break;
        }
        case '/':
        {
        buoc_tra_loi_phan_4://label /
             printf("\nOkey!\nWhat type of 'x'?\nType '1' in case like 4/1=x or '2' in case x/1=4 or '3' 4/x=1\n");
             Cau_tra_loi=getch();
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 1)
             {
                printf("\nType the '4': ");
                scanf("%i", So_bi_chia);
                printf("\nType the '1': ");
                scanf("%i", So_chia);
                printf(endl"X: %lf", So_bi_chia/So_chia endl);//cout << endl <<  "X: " << So_bi_chia/So_chia << endl;
             }
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 2)
             {
                printf("Type the '1': \n");
                scanf("%i", So_chia);
                printf("Type the '4': \n");
                scanf("%i", Thuong);
                printf("X: %ld", So_chia * Thuong);//cout << "X: " << So_chia * Thuong << endl;
             }
             if (Cau_tra_loi == 3)
             {
                printf("Type the '4': \n");
                scanf("%i", So_bi_chia);
                printf("Type the '1': \n");
                scanf("%i", Thuong);
                printf("X: %%lf", So_bi_chia/Thuong);//cout << "X: " << So_bi_chia/Thuong << endl;
             }
             if(Cau_tra_loi<=0 || Cau_tra_loi>=4)
             {
                printf("\nError: Invailid answer");
             }
             break;
        }
        default:
        {
             printf("Error: Invailid answer. To conttinue, press any key!");
             break;
        }
    }
    getch();
    printf("\nPress any key to end the program!");
    exit(0);
}
```

I'm using Codeblock v16.1 and I meet this problem:
error: no matching function for call to 'endl(const char [6], int)' in line 39 and
warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]| in most of line.
The labels are also not work
Plz help me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you transforming C++ code into C code?

Comment: `printf(endl("X: %i", So_hang_thu_nhat + So_hang_con_lai)endl);` -> `printf("\nX: %i\n", So_hang_thu_nhat + So_hang_con_lai);`.

Comment: if i use \n then the codeblocks say:                                                                               
   |error: stray '\' in program|

Comment: `std::cout << std::endl;` is roughly `printf("\n");`.

Comment: the codeblocks not except the endl and the \n in my program